# How to compare two dates in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I kind of assumed it was a string, so I compared it as a string, but not surprisingly it failed. I believe thats how it works in Mysql. I could be wrong as I haven't worked on it in a while. In either case, how can I check if dates are equal in SQLite? I will be using it in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT a._id, b._id, b.start_date,a.event_name, b.start_time, 
b.end_date, b.end_time, b.location FROM events_info b INNER JOIN events a ON
 a._id=b.event_id WHERE b.start_time = '6:00';
```

(added space to make it easier to look at)

Comment: you should have posted your "not-working" code

Comment: I don't see the point as I am 100% positive the time/date comparison is the problem. But if it matters that much I will gladly oblige. Sorry about that.

Comment: By "compare two dates" you mean "compare two times-of-day", right?

Comment: Yes sir. Well no times, like separate, so YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM, but either way you decide to help me with is fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a dedicated DATETIME type.  Normally what people do is make sure they store the date as a formatted string that is consistent; for example, YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.  If you do so, as long as you're consistent, then you can compare dates directly:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE q_date < '2013-01-01 00:00:00';
```

This works because even though the comparison is technically an alphabetical comparison and not a numeric one, dates in a consistent format like this sort alphabetically as well as numerically.

For such a schema, I would suggest storing dates in 24-hour format (the above example is midnight).  Pad months, days, and hours with zeros.  If your dates will span multiple timezones, store them all in UTC and do whatever conversion you need client-side to convert them to the local time zone.

Normally dates and times are stored all in one column.  If you have to have them separated for whatever reason, just make sure you dates are all consistent and your times are all consistent.  For example, dates should all be YYYY-MM-DD and times should all be hh:mm:ss.

The reason that YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss is the preferred format is because when you go from the largest date interval (years) to the smallest (seconds), you can index and sort them very easily and with high performance.

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE q_date = '2012-06-04 05:06:00';
```

would use the index to hone in on the date/time instead of having to do a full table scan.  Or if they're in two separate rows:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE q_date = '2012-06-04' AND q_time = '05:06:00';
```

The key is to make sure that the dates and times are in a consistent format going into the database.  For user-friendly presentation, do all conversion client-side, not in the database.  (For example, convert '2012-06-04 05:06:00' to "1:06am Eastern 6/4/2012".)

If this doesn't answer question, could you please post the exact format that you're using to store your dates and times, and two example dates that you're trying to compare that aren't working the way you expect them to?

Comment: This is true. But whats the point of having the types set aside in the database lol. It just confuses me as to allowing people to make a Date and Time column, but when comparing them, it fails. But I could just make a Text column. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, the answer is for portability.  That way, if you're moving from SQLite to [some other DB system] or vice versa, you don't have to rewrite all of your queries.  Or at least, it's a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. you save my day :)

My working code:- SELECT * FROM LogDetail WHERE time_Detail > '2014-06-18 23:13:00';

Answer (score 7):

Sqlite can not compare dates directly. we need to convert them in seconds as well as integer also.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM Table  
WHERE  
CAST(strftime('%s', date_field)  AS  integer) <=CAST(strftime('%s', '2015-01-01')  AS  integer) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> **1.2 Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

If you look at the examples in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), something like this should get you close to what you want (which, I'm assuming, is 6:00 of the current day):

```
WHERE b.start_time = date('now', 'start of day', '+6 hours')
```